# How to add a clickable padding in Android CheckBox?

Tags: android, onclick, padding, android-checkbox

I want to add **paddings** to Android **CheckBox**, which can perform **onClick** event.

**I tried this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checked"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="28dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**And this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checked"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But both times it's not centered! The right padding has a double width while left padding has no width.

If I use margins like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checked"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="28dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The margin part can not perform **onClick** event.

Comment: can you share the the image of the design you want to implement and short shot of the design you got now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use a **LinearLayout** inside which contains the **CheckBox** and **onClick** method of **LinearLayout** use the same code you are using for **Checkbox**. Update your **XML** as below code:

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_checked"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
      <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checked"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code:**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    .
    .
    .
    LinearLayout layoutChecked = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_checked);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checked);

    layoutChecked..setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onClickedCheckBox();
                }
            });

    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onClickedCheckBox();
                }
            });
    }
     public void onClickedCheckBox(){
      //Do whatever you want to do here
    }
```